# "Type specified in JSON is not compatible" in Newtonsoft for classes appearing in different loaded Assemblies

Tags: c#, json.net

We have a somewhat weird setup where we have a C# SDK which can host different assemblies that are loaded at runtime. We are using the [McMaster DotNetCorePlugins library](https://github.com/natemcmaster/DotNetCorePlugins) to load these assemblies. (The SDK is actually loaded into a Java service that uses JNI to communicate with it, but I don't think that's material to the issue.)

We want to be able to host different versions of an assembly that are loaded side-by-side in the same service/SDK instance, to support parallel development. So the assemblies are mostly identical in terms of classes, namespaces, etc. (They are typically on the same assembly version too, but I've tested using different assembly versions and it does not appear to make a difference)

However, when we load a second assembly and it wants to deserialize some JSON, we get an exception:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Type specified in JSON
> 'LoadedAssembly.BaseClass, LoadedAssembly, Version=4.16.13.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' is not compatible with
> 'LoadedAssembly.DerivedClass, LoadedAssembly, Version=4.16.14.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. Path
> 'Base[0].ruleTarget.groupingSize.$type', line 13, position 68.    at
> Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.ResolveTypeName(JsonReader
> reader, Type& objectType, JsonContract& contract, JsonProperty member,
> JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember,
> String qualifiedTypeName)    at
> Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.ReadMetadataProperties(JsonReader
> reader, Type& objectType, JsonContract& contract, JsonProperty member,
> JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember,
> Object existingValue, Object& newValue, String& id)
>
> ...

It seems like the type information from the first loaded assembly is somehow getting mixed up with the type information from the second loaded assembly in a way that causes this error. Is there any way to work around this issue?

(Newtonsoft 12.0.3, .NET 5.0)

Comment: Are you using `TypeNameHandling`?

Comment: Looks like not in the SDK, but the assemblies we are loading are using it in at least some spots. Mostly `Auto` but in one case they're using `All`. (I'm not really familiar with this feature to be honest - could it be causing the problem?)

Comment: I think it could be. The type definition baked into the Json isn’t the same as the type that it’s trying to deserialise to. Might be worth running the actual JSON.Net code to see exactly what’s happening, maybe there’s a workaround.

Comment: To clarify, the SDK doesn't use `TypeNameHandling` but some of the interfaces the loaded assemblies call can provide a `JsonSettings` object where the assembly code may have it set. However, in this particular failure it's entirely within the loaded assembly code, not calling back into an SDK method

Comment: Check the value of [`TypeNameAssemblyFormatHandling`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_TypeNameAssemblyFormatHandling.htm) used

Comment: Looks like `Simple`. (That's what is in the `JsonSerializerInternalReader` at the spot where the exception is thrown. It's not being set explicitly by our code as far as I can tell - so that's the default?) `TypeNameHandling` is `Auto` FWIW

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252213/discussion-between-ryryguy-and-stuartd).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to user stuartd for pointing me in the direction of `TypeNameHandling`. As it turns out, setting `TypeNameAssemblyFormatHandling.Full` in `JsonSerializerSettings` to use fully qualified assembly names in resolution and caching of type information will keep the assemblies' type information separated, provided that the loaded assemblies have different assembly versions.

That's the easy way. If it's not practical to require that the assemblies have different versions (which is true in my case), there is an alternative. The cache which causes the type information to become intermingled is implemented in the Newtonsoft class [DefaultSerializationBinder](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/bf2e2a78e8febf0006ec647f9bde3aa5bbe0ce72/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/DefaultSerializationBinder.cs). You can replace this with a custom [SerializationBinder](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings_SerializationBinder.htm) that keeps the cache entries for the "identical" assemblies separated.

I was able to do this by copying the `DefaultSerializationBinder` code (plus a few supporting utility classes and methods) into my project, in order to change `private` and `internal` stuff. I'm not going to post the full change here, but the heart of it was this:

```
private string cacheVersion { get; } = $"_{DateTime.UtcNow.Millisecond}";
private StructMultiKey<string, string> DecoratedCacheKey(string assemblyName, string typeName)
{
    string decoratedAssemblyName = assemblyName != null ? $"{assemblyName}{cacheVersion}" : assemblyName;
    return new StructMultiKey<string, string>(decoratedAssemblyName, typeName);
}
```

Since the assemblies are loaded at different times, different `cacheVersions` are created for each. Then, using `DecoratedCacheKey` to store the cached types keeps them separated. Even for assemblies with the same name and version!

(Of course types that *could* be shared are also kept separate; you could write more code to only separate the entries belonging to particular assemblies if you cared to do so.)